# Android Chat UI Modification

Tags: mesibo

I want to modify the UI chat bubbles and also add the attachment option in the chat box to add images, videos or files in the Android App. I am using the UI modules provided by mesibo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this? https://mesibo.com/documentation/ui-modules/android/messaging/

The source code is another place to look into https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android

Comment: I have looked into the ui-modules but there is nothing to modify chat bubbles but if I go with source code then will have to do it from scratch.